# Click location Address use phone GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, gps, maps

I know there is a way to do it but I cannot find it online because every time I try to search it other stuff pops up!

What I am trying to do is have the address of a location displayed like this:

123 Street
City, St 12345

The user of my android app can click the address and it will use the phones gps to find the way to the location from the current location of the user.

I need help finding the resources like website, or something...Thank you!

Comment: Check out this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393286/mobile-web-driving-directions-from-current-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this website

Android – Creating links using linkify | aviyehuda.com

```
    TextView myLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    myLocation.setText("The addres you want");
    Linkify.addLinks(myLocation , Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "reverse geocoding" (when I understood you correctly). Check out http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/android-google-maps-tutorial-part-8-geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding/